# Specifying which screen my application should open on

Tags: wpf

I've created two WPF applications that are designed to run full screen on the same server with dual monitors.

Is it possible to specify which application opens on which screen?

I currently have the executable on different monitors desktop which works but ideally I'd like to control this programmatically.

If that isn't possible, then I could move the application into a WPF web client and open in two full screen Internet Explorer windows but again I'd need to specify which ones load on which screens.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to set the Window.StartupLocation to manual for both of your exe's and then you will have to manually set the Window.Top and Window.Left to the coordinates for the monitor you want each to show up on.

You will probably want to use the Screen class to determine where each screen is at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

Comment: Hi,

Thanks - you pointed me in the right direction.




int screenIndexToUse = 0;
Screen[] scr = Screen.AllScreens;
this.Left = scr[screenIndexToUse].Bounds.Left;
this.Top = scr[screenIndexToUse].Bounds.Top;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;